# ImportError : No module named app.core.admin.login

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, flask, virtualenv

I have copied my project folder from Windows to Mac and created virtualenv and downloaded the packages for flask on Mac.

My current project structure is :

```
MyApplication
            |-app                 
                |- core
                       |-admin
                              |-__init__.py
                              |-login.py
            |-__init__.py
run.py
```

In the __init __.py file inside the app folder I have imported Login Class from the login.py module as :

__init __.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request
from app.core.admin.login import Login
```

but when I execute ./run.py I get an error

```
from app.core.admin.login import Login
ImportError: No module named core.admin.login
```

But the same project is running fine on Windows.

Comment: its better you maintain a server repository like github so that you could pull code changes into authorized machines... and perform several git operations like resetting if you get any errors in the future any case you think if you have deleted any files in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `__init__.py` files in those package folders. You application structure should look like this:

Each folder should have it's own `__init__.py`.

```
MyApplication/ 
   |-- app/ 
          |-- __init__.py
          |-- core/
                 |-- __init__.py
                 |-- admin/
                        |-- __init__.py
                        |-- login.py
```

Comment: I do have it but I haven't written anything in it and the same working fine on windows

Comment: You may have been using Python 3.3+ on Windows which supports package directories with no `__init__.py`. See https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages